# How to insert an image in this particular template (ICLR 2022)

Tags: syntax

Link to overleaf template: https://www.overleaf.com/latex/templates/template-for-iclr-2021-conference-submission/mmpfhsxmqdkp

I tried this code:

```
\begin{figure}
    \centering
    \includegraphics{pipe.png}
    \caption{Caption}
    \label{fig:my_label}
\end{figure}
```

**Error:** "Undefined Control Sequence" for \includegraphics.

Comment: I have made sure to check the image path. That is not the issue.

Comment: if includegraphics is not defined then you have not defined it, add `\usepackage{graphicx}`

Comment: Thank you so much. Forgot about the most simple thing haha.

Comment: I'm getting the same error for ICLR 2023, when using `%\usepackage{graphicx}` in the preamble. Is there a difference with LaTeX2e as an update? I followed the documentation here: http://latexref.xyz/Graphics.html and it says use `\include{graphicx}` but it's still not working.